# What does the Assault End Time mean in HoxHud?

Tags: payday-2

I recently got HoxHud and love all the extra information it gives you, especially the assault waves, but was wondering what the 'ASSAULT END TIME:' meant? It shows a number but no units. Does that number mean the number of seconds until the assault ends from that point or the number of seconds from the start of the assault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates the timer to when the assault ends. So when the timer is out, the phase ends.

```
self.assault_phase_text = "Assault Phase: "
self.assault_spawn_amount_text = "Spawns Left: "
self.assault_time_left_text = "End Time:
```

Pulled from the code for the mod.

Comment: Please clarify. The asker asked what the timer indicated. The timer just indicates numbers. Is this the time in seconds? Minutes? Hours? Milliseconds?